# Checking that a given email address is valid as a google account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-oauth, google-authentication

In my application, for functionality, a user will enter his Gmail or google workspace email id and I have to verify if it is a valid google account. Is there a way do this?
something like this should happen

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to log them in? using Oauth2 if its not valid that will fail.

Comment: my intention is just to verify the valid google account, not to log them in for now. I need to kind of implement the exact thing as in the image.

Comment: No because the user must grant you permission to access anything related to identity unless it is a domain account where the administrator has that right. Hackers and spammers would love to be able to check.